# что-то с ClassPath в скомпилированном jar-е

Tags: java

имею проект (Spring), который отлично запускается и работает под Eclipc-ом. Все файлы находятся. Технически они находятся в src/main/resources.
 Читаю например файл в коде так:

```
private final String KEY_FILE = "AccessKey.key";

private void setKey() {

    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {});
    Resource resource = appContext.getResource(KEY_FILE);
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) appContext).close();
    // работали ради этого      
    serverKey = readFile(resource);
}



private String readFile (Resource resource) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;
    try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  sb.append(line);   }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    finally {if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
    return sb.toString();
}
```

после экспорта проекта в jar, запуск приводит к ошибке:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [AccessKey.key] cannot be opened because it does not exist

at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
```

подозреваю при компиляции не задана передача ClassPath в jar. 
подскажите куда посмотреть.

Comment: в догонку. файл в сборке jar - есть и лежит он в resources/ . Если я его кладу в корень сборки - он читается.

Comment: посмотрите про maven-plugin-ы и <outputDirectory>. Возможно, Вам это поможет

Comment: все правильно не работает - файл читаете в корне, а кладете в resources

Answer (score 0):

1. Самое простое и надёжное - это сделать для запуска приложения командный файл BAT/CMD или SH и в нём прописать все необходимые параметры, включая CLASSPATH.
2. Если же очень хочется всё запихнуть внутрь JAR, то смотрите тут как включить описание CLASS-PATH в MANIFEST.MF [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)
3. Можно сделать указанное в п.2 с помощью maven [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)